# Code not returning correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My code is not working as intended.

```
declare @start int = patindex('_%48%_', asciiValue),
        @end int = (patindex('_%48%_', asciiValue) +1)

select * from imItem 
where asciiValue like ('%48%')
and asciiValue in (SUBSTRING(asciiValue, 1, @start-1) + '79' + SUBSTRING(asciiValue,@end+1,LEN(asciiValue)))
```

It is supposed to search the database for rows where the column AsciiValue includes chars '48', and select them in addition to the rows which are identical in field AsciiValue to the one mentioned before, but the only difference is that in the same place where '48' was in the other row, this row has a '79'.

For instance,
89643931**48**134122
89643931**79**134122
will be selected.
Please help.

EDIT: To clarify, the code will only produce the rows ONLY IF the row contains the value 48, and then the other row contains 79 in the same index.

Comment: You are declaring `@start` and `@end` once.   Those values will not adjust to each row of the table.   In fact your code should have an error in the declaration, since it looks like `asciivalue` is a column, and the declarations don't have a FROM clause.   I recommend you post a script that fully reproduces the problem.

Comment: @TabAlleman, do you mean to say that the local variables should be put into a loop so that they are redeclared as a new value every new row?

Comment: What if a row has more than one `48`? Replace all? Replace one? Replace and don't replace in every possible combination?

Comment: Hint: [`STUFF(asciiValue, CHARINDEX('48', asciiValue), 2, '79')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql). Don't torture yourself with `SUBSTRING`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't think he's looking to do a replace here.

Comment: @TabAlleman: problem reformulation: locate all rows that look like some other row except with `48` replaced by `79`. Hey look, a replace.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am not looking to replace, I want all values to stay as are. However you have raised a good point. There will be certain cases where there is more than one 48 in the row, but I am looking for the rows where 48 and 79 are in identical indexes.

Comment: @javajunkee: *replace* does not mean `UPDATE`. I'm not getting my point across to two people now, for some reason. :-P If you had asked "I'm looking for 'BANANA' and then 'BONANA'", my response is "ah, so you want all rows that look like 'BANANA' with the first 'A' replaced with an 'O', if such rows exist". It does not mean any rows are getting changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be answer to your question. First part of the UNION selects numbers with 79 in it that match to some other number with 48 in its place. The second part hunts down those with 48 in it and are otherwise identical to those with 79.

```
SELECT asciiValue FROM imItem WHERE
asciiValue IN (
    SELECT concat(substring(asciiValue, 0,patindex('%48%', asciiValue)),'79', substring(asciiValue, patindex('%48%', asciiValue) +2,99)) 
    FROM imItem 
    WHERE asciiValue LIKE ('%48%')
)
UNION
SELECT asciiValue FROM imItem WHERE
asciiValue IN (
    SELECT concat(substring(asciiValue, 0,patindex('%79%', asciiValue)),'48', substring(asciiValue, patindex('%79%', asciiValue) +2,99)) 
    FROM imItem 
    WHERE asciiValue LIKE ('%79%')
)
```

And little bit cleaner version as per @Jeroen Mostert comment.

```
SELECT * FROM imItem WHERE
asciiValue IN (
    SELECT STUFF ( asciiValue , CHARINDEX('48', asciiValue) , 2, '79' )
    FROM imItem 
    WHERE asciiValue LIKE ('%48%')
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM imItem WHERE
asciiValue IN (
    SELECT STUFF ( asciiValue , CHARINDEX('79', asciiValue) , 2, '48' )
    FROM imItem 
    WHERE asciiValue LIKE ('%79%')
)
```

For input like this

```
8964393148134122
8964393179134122
8964393179134123
7964393148134122
```

Returns

```
asciiValue
8964393148134122
8964393179134122
```

**EDIT** OK, let's try it one more time

```
SELECT i.* FROM imItem i
JOIN imItem j
    ON (REPLACE(i.asciiValue, '79', '48') = REPLACE(j.asciiValue, '79', '48')
        OR REPLACE(i.asciiValue, '48', '79') = REPLACE(j.asciiValue, '48', '79'))
    AND i.asciivalue <> j.asciivalue
WHERE i.asciiValue LIKE '%48%' OR i.asciiValue LIKE '%79%'
```

**EDIT 2** This one might be more robust

```
DECLARE @i int = 1
WHILE @i < 18
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM imItem AS a
    JOIN imItem AS b
        ON a.asciiValue <> b.asciiValue
    WHERE
        a.asciiValue = STUFF(b.asciiValue, @i, 2, '48')
        AND b.asciiValue = STUFF(a.asciiValue, @i, 2, '79')

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: This will not just give all rows containing a `48` that have a corresponding row with `79`, but also the other way around, which was not asked for. (It will also only work for the first instance of `48`, but that might be sufficient.) Also, if I can nitpick further, this does not select *rows*, it only selects the `asciiValue` values. This matters: `UNION` performs an implicit `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert OP asked for pairs where 48 and 79 are in the same place. If there can be more than one occurrence of 48, then you are right it might not work correctly. And asciiValue is replaced with * to select whole row.

Comment: It is possible in some cases that there will be more than one instance of 48. Also, for the second code, an error is being thrown where 'The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.' What does this mean? And how do I solve it?

Comment: I am in the process of running this script (it is taking >30 min to compile). My question is, does this not select all rows with a 48 or a 79, even when there is one difference elsewhere?

Comment: It will select rows, where is 48 and there exists row with 79 in that place and vice versa. There might be multiple instances of this difference. And yes it will be terribly slow due to REPLACE on both sides of JOIN.

Comment: It will also match numbers `793379` and `483348` So as long as you are OK with it, then it will work.

Comment: Yes, It worked perfectly. I tried adjusting the code (changing 48 to 49, and 79 to 73) but now it does not return the desired results as the original code had. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: It possibly matched some numbers, where there were multiple occurrences of 49 or 73. See my edit 2 for another, hopefully more robust, solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM imItem WHERE asciiValue LIKE '%48%' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM imItem WHERE asciiValue IN (
    SELECT STUFF(asciiValue, CHARINDEX('48', asciiValue), 2, '79') 
    FROM imItem 
    WHERE asciiValue LIKE '%48%'
)
```

is a near-literal translation of what you're asking for, except that it does not take care of a row having more than one instance of `48` (it only looks for correspondences with the first instance replaced) and it does not explicitly try to put rows in a one-to-one relationship in case that's required (if there is more than one row matching the original one with `48` replaced, it will return all of them, not exactly as many as there are with `48`).

Comment: Unfortuantely it isn't see his EDIT. "ONLY IF the row contains the value 48, and then the other row contains 79 in the same index." It is equivalent to my first version. I think that I might have finally figured it out. See my last edit. BTW: Thanks for hint with STUFF. Feel free to tear it up :-)

Comment: @MarekVitek: the question is insufficiently precise. The OP is free to indicate this answer is incorrect, but I can't divine that from the question as asked (or the input set, which doesn't have enough examples).